# Jquery altFormat datepicker issue in rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui

I have a form with a date input

```
<div class="form-inputs">
<%= f.input :day, as: :string, input_html: {id: 'date'} %>
```

And i'm using a datepicker jquery object that I make at the bottom of the page

```
<script>$(function(){$("#date").datepicker();});</script>
```

When I have this, everything works, and the datepicker displays as it should, but it displays as month date year, whereas the db and rails takes date month year. So some work when they should not ie (05/07/2013) and then obviously when the date is over 12, it rejects it saying that the field is blank.

I have tried

```
<script>$(function(){$("#date").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",altFormat: "ddmmyy"});</script>

<script>$(function(){$("#date").datepicker({ altFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });</script>
```

And none of them have worked, am I missing something or do I need to change something somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples in the docs are little incomplete. The [`altFormat`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altFormat) option is only used if you also specify the [`altField`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField):

> **altFormat**
>   The `dateFormat` to be used for the `altField` option.

and:

> **altField**
>   An input element that is to be updated with the selected date from the datepicker. Use the `altFormat` option to change the format of the date within this field.

The corresponding examples only show each option being used alone but you need to specify `altField` if you want to use `altFormat`. The usual approach would be to use a hidden input as the actual date that gets sent to the server and then hook up the user-visible date selector to the hidden input using `altField` with something like this:

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    altField: '#some-hidden-field',
    altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/jWT5G/